# Risch differential equation algorithm by Bronstein

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms, computer-algebra-systems

I was implementing the [algorithm](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0747717108800065/1-s2.0-S0747717108800065-main.pdf?_tid=3633d764-fbab-11e3-8b61-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1403620032_19e5e991939a655d89283a2be42386f6) by Manuel Bronstein for solving the Risch differential equation.

My question is:

> What does Bronstein mean by "Order" in the algorithm poly_DE (exponential case, page 56)?

Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that if you expand $Q$ as a Laurent series about $0$:

$$ Q(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n $$

then "a lower bound on the order at $0$ of $Q$", $b$, is defined such that there is guaranteed to be a $c\geq b$ such that either $a_c\neq 0$ or $a_{-c}\neq 0$ or both.

So it is, in a sense, the opposite of the "order of vanishing" of a function.